# DynamicMapsService .AddListener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I have been working on a simulation , where it was using MapSDK from Google. Now , we were asked to completely move out of 'Google Maps SDK for Unity' and use another asset from the Unity asset store called "world composer". So instead of Google MapSDK generating building and all, using the "world composer" , I just import the satellite ground image of a location like any game objects. I am trying to remove all lines of code in the present simulation that uses Google Maps SDK.

The simulation has the following individual c# scripts.

1. ProtectedZonesManager.cs //Generates a bubble like structure called protectd zones
2. AI_DroneManager.cs //Generates a swarm of drones which orbits around the protected zones

and few other scripts
3. AADManagers.cs is a centralized scripts managing all the scripts above

I come across this line which uses delegates in AADManagers.cs

### "DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents. Loaded.RemoveListener(mapsLoadedAction);"
as below.

I am trying to understand what it means or does and how to replace it , so it doesn't have any association with MapsSDK (or DynamicMapsService). The new asset doesn't have any events nor does it need listeners(I think), as it is just a game object(with image).  Any idea on that would be very helpful. Thank you

```
 UnityAction<MapLoadedArgs> mapLoadedAction = null;
    mapLoadedAction = new UnityAction<MapLoadedArgs>(delegate (MapLoadedArgs args)
    {
        StartActorManagers();
        DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded.RemoveListener(mapLoadedAction);
    });

    DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded.AddListener(mapLoadedAction);
    



}

/// <summary>
/// Starts all actor managers scripts
/// </summary>
private void StartActorManagers()
{
    ProtectedZonesManager.PostMapLoadStart();
    AI_DroneManager.PostMapLoadStart();
    //MissileLauncherManager.PostMapLoadStart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does it do / mean

well there are the two lines

```
DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded.RemoveListener(mapLoadedAction);
```

and

```
DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded.AddListener(mapLoadedAction);
```

Basically what actually happens is, the second one is executed first!

You add a listener to the event called `DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded`. So once this event is invoked (by the MapsSDK apparently) you execute everything placed inside the `mapLoadedAction` which is

```
StartActorManagers();
DynamicMapsService.MapsService.Events.MapEvents.Loaded.RemoveListener(mapLoadedAction);
```

were you remove that very same listener so it is only executed ONCE and if the same event is invoked again later (for whatever reason) you ignore that later invocation.

---

Now how do remove/replace it

This depends very much on how exactly your new library works. If it has events as well you would probably do something similar but there is no way for us to tell without knowing the API of hat new asset you want to use ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The new asset I am using is "world composer" which generates a satellite image of terrain anywhere around the world(for example). The generated image is just a game object and it doesn't have any events like the Dynamic Maps. I tried to just call the "StartActorManagers()" function instead of delegates, but it seems to be not working. I would be happy if all the code(drones/protected zones) just worked without the Maps being generated and just running in the Unity's default plane. So , I can inset my new asset later without codes.

Comment: @PrabhakaranJeyamohan as said this depends completely on how the project and those SDKs work and which APIs they provide .. You can't just replace libraries and expect everything to work just like that ... except the project architecture was really planned and implemented well ;)